# How do I split a string into parially a set of values, partially an array, in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to split a string of the form

NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 x y z ...

where x y z is of varying length (the number of items) into something like:

```
[num1, num2, num3, the_rest_of_the_string_without_splitting] = split(" ")
```

Is there a way to do it in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's an argument called `maxsplit` you can use:

```py
t = "NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 x y z"                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

t.split(" ", maxsplit=3)  # => ['NUM1', 'NUM2', 'NUM3', 'x y z']
```

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements).

Comment: and you don't even need to define it, `t.split(" ", 3)` works too!